# How can we make a test dependent on another test in testcafe studio

Tags: testing, automation, automated-tests, e2e-testing, testcafe

I have a scenario with 3 tests, test1, test2, and test3.
In test1 I need to request access and check the pending request count.
In test2 another user needs to request access and we need to check if pending request count is increased. 
In test3 I need to accept the request and see if the pending count is decreased.

We had a bug wherein test1 failed. If test1 failed there is no point in executing test2 and test3 as the basic feature is not working. When test1 fails we need to skip test2 and test3.

I created a fixture for the above 3 tests but could not find a solution to make test2 and test3 dependent on test1. How can we achieve this in testcafe studio.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The functional tests' best practice is to write test cases independently of one another. I do not recommend you implement separate tests that depend on the previous tests run. Instead, you can use the [Test Hooks](https://docs.devexpress.com/TestCafeStudio/401074/test-directory-structure/hooks) feature to setup and tear down the necessary actions for each of your test cases.

For instance, in the 'before each' hook, you can request access to each test and test the necessary functionality.